# Zeebus Puzzle #4

Tags: word, rebus

Take a look at the puzzle below, and take a guess at what it shows...

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is it

> Deep Sea Sub-marine (Deep [tall] C Sub [under] marine)

Comment: Well done. Beat me to it +1

Comment: Great answer! (+1)

Comment: Nice work, El-Guest  and Reibello had a good answers too, but this is the intended solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> A Sailor on the High Sea?

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @Reibello's answer, could it be

> A Marine on the High Sea?